# Change the position of the dateRangeInput() diary box in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, date-range

Is there a way to display the box with the available dates a little lower than the default position after clicking a `dateRangeInput()`? I have an issue in my original app which I do not know why happens and therefore I cannot recreate it.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPagePlus(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(
          ".control-sidebar-tabs {display:none;}"
        )
      )
    ),
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
    ),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
      background = "dark",
      uiOutput("sel"),
      uiOutput("dr")
    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$dr <- renderUI({
      dateRangeInput("range_date", "Enter Date Range", start = "2001-01-01",
                     end   = "2010-12-31" , format = "yyyy-mm")
    })
    output$sel<-renderUI({
      selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                  c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                    "Transmission" = "am",
                    "Gears" = "gear"))
    })

  }
)
```

Comment: that's strange, I don't have this display problem with your example

Comment: neither do I but I do not know why it happens in order to recreate it. I have a more complex app and anything may provoke this

Comment: I think that the server shouldn't be the cause of that, so that's something in the ui.  I would say it is not very likely that inputs create that, so maybe it is related to HTML tags.